# Using induction to prove a string-related equation

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

The reverse of a string is given as $rev(x)$ for any string $x$. For example, $rev(abcdefg) = gfedcba$.

The problem is as follows:

> Prove, using induction on the length of the string, that $rev(rev(s)) = s$ (read: "the reverse of the reverse of a string $s$ is $s$") for any string $s \in \Sigma^*$.

My inductive proof is as follows:

> **Basis**: For $|s| = 0$, $s = \epsilon$. Therefore, $rev(rev(\epsilon)) = rev(\epsilon) = \epsilon$.
>
> **Hypothesis**: Assume $rev(rev(s)) = s$ is true for $|s| = k$, where $k \ge 1$.
>
> **Inductive Step**: Show that $rev(rev(s)) = s$ is true for $|s| = k + 1$.
>
> From the assumption that $rev(rev(s)) = s$ is true for a string $s$ of length $k$, the statement must be true for another string $s$ of length $k + 1$.

I would like to know whether my proof suffices. Did I make any mistakes on evaluating after the inductive step?

Comment: Is it necessary to prove it using induction? Contradiction works equally well.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Yes, I believe the problem asks me to use induction.

Comment: Well I for one think that the statement is definitely true by common sense and I guess your proof is correct as long as you include the answer in it.

Answer (score 1):

The basis is correct, but the hypothesis and inductive step need to be strengthened:

Hypothesis: Assume $rev(rev(s))=s$ is true for **any** $|s|=k$, where $k\ge1$.

Inductive Step: Show that $rev(rev(s))=s$
is true for **any** $s$ such that $|s|=k+1$.

From the assumption that $rev(rev(s))=s$ is true for **all** strings $s$ of length $k$, the statement must be true for **all** strings $s$ of length $k+1$.